# Concurrently zipping and download file performance issues

Tags: java, performance, servlets, zip

I have a servlet that compresses file while its downloading. My problem slow process is really slow. I'm zipping files coz files will be more than 1GB. But downloading process is so slow. What kind of betterment would you suggest me?

```
package mainpackage;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class DownloadZipServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public DownloadZipServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment;filename=download.zip");

        ServletOutputStream sos;
        ZipOutputStream zos;
        InputStream fis;
        List<File> filesToDownload = new ArrayList<File>();

        filesToDownload.add(new File(getDirectory(), "download.png"));
        filesToDownload.add(new File(getDirectory(), "downloadpdf.pdf"));

        sos = response.getOutputStream();
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(sos);


        for (File fileToSend : filesToDownload) {

            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(fileToSend.getName());
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);

            fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToSend));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[131072*100];
            int readBytesCount = 0;
            while ((readBytesCount = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, readBytesCount);
            }
            fis.close();
            sos.flush();
            zos.flush();
            zos.closeEntry();
        }
        zos.close();
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public String getDirectory() {
        Properties prop;
        String home;
        String fileSeparator;
        String directoryName;

        prop = System.getProperties();
        home = prop.getProperty("user.dir").toString();
        fileSeparator = prop.getProperty("file.separator").toString();
        directoryName = "FileToDownload";

        return home + fileSeparator + directoryName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Downloading a gigabyte does tend to be slow even if compressed. Post some code.

Comment: I mean download speed is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple things you could think about:

1) If you can, prezip the files in a zip file and cache the zip file on the server filesystem, this way you don't incur the cost of compressing the content each request.

2) If you control the client doing the download, you could download several chunks of the file concurrently and assemble them on the client allowing you to saturate the bandwidth available to the client. This [blog entry](http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/) gives some background.

3) Try playing with varying levels of compression to see which works best with the server/network/client configuration that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I know all J2EE application servers support a mechanism to zip files based on format for browsers.
For example in tomcat you can use http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html. and if you use tomcat APR http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html that might even have a better performance.
I used the configuration below and it tomcat compresses javascript,css,.. files plus some big pdf files that I have.

```
<Connector compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,text/css,application/javascript,application/pdf" compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" connectionTimeout="20000" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" port="8085" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

I used tomcat 7 but I'm sure it works on other versions also on other application servers out there

Answer (score -1):

This slowness causes from compression level. Default zipoutstream compression level is set to -1. I don't know its(-1 compression level) meaning but we can set compression level from zero to nine(0-9).

```
zos.setLevel(0);
```

i added this method to get zero compression rate.Now, My compression and sending data to client concurrently works very fast.

Comment: Ah that's a zero compression method. You can set from 0 to 9. I choose 0 compression because i just need to send multiple files in a packaged zip file. But i can set it to 2-3-4. this will working fast aswell